# Loop through files in subfolder in python with google API

Tags: pandas, dataframe, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-client

In google drive, let say I have a folder call "main", within "main", I have subfolders "A", "B", and "C". There are googlesheets in those subfolder.

I want to loop through the subfolders and read the google sheets using pandas using google API. So far I have something to read the folders (including the main folder) but it spits out a lot of information about those folders too. Not sure if my approach is right, and any help is appreciated. thanks!

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from Google import Create_Service

from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from getfilelistpy import getfilelist


SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'


store = file.Storage('token.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('../HP_assay/client_secret_file.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)

resource = {
    "oauth2": creds.authorize(Http()),
    "id": "1HkAYszdQa3OjTC59uQd8dbtXNjs1sV2R",
    "fields": "files(name,id)",
}
res = getfilelist.GetFileList(resource)  # or r = getfilelist.GetFolderTree(resource)
r = getfilelist.GetFolderTree(resource)
listing = list(list(res.items()))
print(listing)  

# columns = []
# for i in listing:
#     columns.append(i[0])
# resource_info = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(listing)
```

For the google import, this is the code I grabbed from google.

```
import pickle
import os
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow, InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import datetime

def Create_Service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes):
    print(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, scopes, sep='-')
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file
    API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
    API_VERSION = api_version
    SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
    print(SCOPES)

    cred = None

    pickle_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}.pickle'
    # print(pickle_file)

    if os.path.exists(pickle_file):
        with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)

    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            cred = flow.run_local_server()

        with open(pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(cred, token)

    try:
        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
        print(API_SERVICE_NAME, 'service created successfully')
        return service
    except Exception as e:
        print('Unable to connect.')
        print(e)
        return None

def convert_to_RFC_datetime(year=1900, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0):
    dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0).isoformat() + 'Z'
    return dt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetFileList` method returns the folder tree and the file list in each subfolder. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/getfilelistpy) I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue of `So far I have something to read the folders (including the main folder) but it spits out a lot of information about those folders too.`.

If you want to retrieve only the file list, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
res = getfilelist.GetFileList(resource)  # or r = getfilelist.GetFolderTree(resource)
r = getfilelist.GetFolderTree(resource)
listing = list(list(res.items()))
print(listing) 

# columns = []
# for i in listing:
#     columns.append(i[0])
# resource_info = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(listing)
```

#### To:

```
res = getfilelist.GetFileList(resource)
fileListInEachFolder = res.get("fileList", [])
allFilesInFolder = sum([e.get("files", []) for e in fileListInEachFolder], [])
# print(fileListInEachFolder)
print(allFilesInFolder)

# If you want to convert it to a dataframe, please test the following script.
listing = [[e[f] for f in ['name', 'id']] for e in allFilesInFolder]
resource_info = pd.DataFrame(listing, columns=['name', 'id'])
```

- When this modified script is run, `allFilesInFolder` is as follows.

  ```json
  [
    {'id': '###folderId1###', 'name': 'filename1'},
    {'id': '###folderId2###', 'name': 'filename2'},
    {'id': '###folderId3###', 'name': 'filename3'},
    ,
    ,
    ,
  ]
  ```
- If you want to retrieve the file list in each subfolder, please use `fileListInEachFolder`.

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that your showing script works without errors and your client can be used for retrieving the file metadata from Google Drive. Please be careful about this.
- The whole modified script of your showing script is as follows.

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from Google import Create_Service

from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from getfilelistpy import getfilelist


SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'


store = file.Storage('token.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('../HP_assay/client_secret_file.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)

resource = {
    "oauth2": creds.authorize(Http()),
    "id": "1HkAYszdQa3OjTC59uQd8dbtXNjs1sV2R",
    "fields": "files(name,id)",
}

# I modified the below script.
res = getfilelist.GetFileList(resource)
fileListInEachFolder = res.get("fileList", [])
allFilesInFolder = sum([e.get("files", []) for e in fileListInEachFolder], [])
# print(fileListInEachFolder)
print(allFilesInFolder)

listing = [[e[f] for f in ['name', 'id']] for e in allFilesInFolder]
resource_info = pd.DataFrame(listing, columns=['name', 'id'])
```

#### Reference:

- [getfilelistpy](https://pypi.org/project/getfilelistpy/)

Comment: curious - in the res.get() or e.get() line, how come the string "fileList" and "files" is used? if I change the name of those strings, it doesnt work anymore.

Comment: @wew044 About your additional question of `curious - in the res.get() or e.get() line, how come the string "fileList" and "files" is used? if I change the name of those strings, it doesnt work anymore.`, is this information useful? https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=get#dict.get